# Table not align according to design

Tags: html, html-table

I have created a  table, table data and tablerow to align my things together nicely. in the design view of asp.net, it shows that the table are align nicely together like the picture shown below:

[image]

However when I enter into the websites, it look so distorted:

[image]

I'm also not very sure why would there be such a drastic difference between the design in asp.net and browser. Below is my html code for my table which I can't really see a problem in it.

```
<h2 align="center">Officer&#39;s Profile</h2>
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td rowspan="6" colspan="4" width="50%">
            <b>Profile Picture</b>
            <br />
            <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <br />
           <b>Rank</b>
            <br />
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
            <br />

            <br />
        </td>

        <td align="left">
           <b> Police ID :</b>
            <asp:Label ID="lblPoliceID" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
            <br />

        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td align="left">
            <b>Full Name :</b> 
            <asp:Label ID="lblFullName" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
            <br />

        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td align="left">
           <b> Email :</b> <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
            <br />

        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td align="left">
            <b>Contact :</b> <asp:Label ID="lblContact" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
            <br />

        </td>
    </tr>

                    <tr>  
        <td align="left">
            <b>Posted To :</b>
            <asp:Label ID="lblLocation" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
            <br />

        </td>
    </tr>


        <tr>
            <td align="left"><b>Address : </b>
                <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <br />
            </td>
            </tr>
```

I'm trying to make it look alike in the design view of asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<td rowspan="6" colspan="4" width="50%" height ="500p"x>
```

to

```
<td rowspan="6" colspan="4" width="50%" height="500px" style="vertical-align:top">
```

Comment: still the same though. the postedto and address label still stretches far apart like the image above.

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan Are there lots of new lines or `<br />` tags under Changi NPC's entry?

Comment: unfortunately there isn't.